# How can I build a Visual Studio solution when the bin and obj directories are tracked by TFS?

Tags: tfs

I'm working on a TFS project where the previous developers have included everything in source control - including the `bin` and `obj` folders.

When I try to build the solution, I get a few errors because all of the files in the `bin` and `obj` folder are locked as read only.

For reasons I can't control, these folders have to be tracked in TFS. How else can I fix the problems caused when I try to build the project and get errors because these folders are locked?

How can I build the solution without checking out these folders every single time?

Comment: @BobbyB I'm interested to know why you can't just set these files to ignore? There's no need to have them tracked, they're generated by a build every single time. There's literally nothing in there worth tracking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As previously mentioned, there is no reason to have have bin and obj folders included in source control, their contents are volatile.

But if you really have no control over that, you simply need to make the appropriate folders and files writeable so they can be overwritten, or delete the bin and obj folders after making them writeable. This is relatively straightfoward, there are a couple of ways to achieve it, and it requires changing the TFSBuild.proj file for the appropriate build.

To make a specific file writable, use this:

```
<Attrib Files="[path to your file]" ReadOnly="False"></Attrib>
```

For making the contents of a whole folder writable, use batching to get a list of the files, then iterate over them using the `attrib` task:

```
<Target Name="MakeFilesWriteable">
    <Attrib Files="@(TargetFiles)" ReadOnly="false" />
</Target>

<ItemGroup>
    <TargetFiles Include="[path to bin folder]\**\*.*" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Alternatively you can execute a Delete on the bin folder:

```
<RemoveDir Condition="Exists('[path to bin folder]')" Directories="[path to bin folder]" />
```

With the exception of the batching example, these tasks can be placed directly within the `BeforeCompileSolution` override target of the build proj file; for the batching example you simply do a call target. Pick and choose which method you want to use, then your `BeforeCompileSolution` will look something like this:

```
<Target Name="BeforeCompileSolution" >
    <CallTarget Targets="MakeFilesWriteable" />

    <Attrib Files="[path to your file]" ReadOnly="False"></Attrib>

    <RemoveDir Condition="Exists('[path to bin folder]')" Directories="[path to bin folder]" />
</Target>
```

Answer (score 9):

Don't add the `obj` and `bin` folders to source control. To remove them from TFS, open Source Control Explorer in Visual Studio, simply right-click on the folders and choose "Delete".

If you can't remove them then you should ask the person who has control over TFS. I don't see any reason to add these folders to TFS so it shouldn't be a "constraint".

Comment: I agree with the sentiment of your answer, however the OP has stated that he has no control over the inclusion of those folders.

Comment: I agree - it completely sucks that they're in there.  I can't remove them, I've asked the lead to do so and I've been denied.

Comment: @BobbyB Did the lead say *why*? It may be that they don't realize the directories should be removed because they're auto-generated on every build.

Answer (score 2):

Yon can use the powershell to delete the bin & obj folders recursively.

```
Get-ChildItem .\ -include bin,obj -Recurse | foreach ($_) { remove-item $_.fullname -Force -Recurse }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a suggestion that is not technical.  Since someone else created this problem for you, make it their problem.  Tell them, and anyone else who matters, that you can't build and it's because of what they did.  They broke the build; they should fix it.  All the technical workarounds suggested here are nice, but they really just skirt the true problem.